# Antifreeze poured in instead of oil at oil change

Tags: oil-change, antifreeze

Poured a gallon of antifreeze in oil input top of the engine after draining the oil. Did not start engine. Left open to dry out. A friend needing money did this, but I put the 50/50 next to a quart of oil, I had left the gallon of oil in the trunk.

I'm being told I was lucky that he caught the mistake. It is supposed to be OK in the morning to put the oil in, but I said wait till 12.

What should I do really?

Answer (score 7):

If you had enough antifreeze in the oil to foul your filter, then you have too much antifreeze in your oil for safety.

Drain again, change the oil again. Sorry, but otherwise your antifreeze+oil will become milkshake/mousse in the crank, plug oil channels, and then destroy your engine.

Answer (score 6):

If you did not start it and all the antifreeze drained out then fill with oil and you should be good to go.

Your engine might need more than a quart to fill to the correct level though.

Once you have run the engine with the fresh oil, check that it is not contaminated by antifreeze just in case some did not come out. If so then change the oil again.

Comment: Thank you, I was told the filter would be OK, but when I turned it upside down this morning a lot of what appeared to me a mix came out, so I put it on a little oil heater set on low that was in a room, when I emptied it again it did look mostly like oil, but does the engine oil circulate continuously through the filter? I think maybe I should get a new filter. It's foggy today but will get up to 68 by lunch. I don't know exactly how much motor territory might have moisture in it which might be trapped in there because the temps overall right now are low, but over freezing.

Comment: That's an answer @PcMan

Comment: And, it should be said, probably think twice before letting this guy work on your car again...

Comment: My neighbor grabbed him to do work too, so he  was running back and forth, But I did put the antifreeze and a quart of oil on the porch but the gallon of oil was in the trunk. He should have read the container but he was rushing around trying to get as much money as he could from my more wealthy neighbor who had a bigger job to be done. I only hired him because I knew he needed the money and he has done this for me in the past. I did change the filter. I plan to find a new pvc valve, maybe that will help. I will change it again, maybe how many miles?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't drain out the reservoir out then you can run the Anti-freeze in the system the anti-freeze will actually set on fire, just not immediately. once it reaches a temp of about 650-750 degrees Fahrenheit it will though. If it has gone through the oil filter, then it will have to in fact be replaced. the insoluble will clog the filter which would start to cause damage to the engine. you'll notice if it's clogged if when it runs then the engine sputters and occasionally belches black smoke.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Except inside the combustion chamber, to my knowledge, there's no part of the engine which *should* reach 650 °F under normal operation. I guess an exhaust manifold could, however, as many times as I've seen antifreeze hit an exhaust manifold, I've never seen it catch fire before. While it is known antifreeze itself can catch fire, will it? Unlikely, even under the worst conditions.

Comment: We left the top oil cap off and the plug out and let it drain over night, but I was told that it still was dripping a little but about two hours later the guy showed up and put in the new filter and put in the oil. How long should I wait to change it or is there something else that needs doing? I have run it about maybe 150 miles I think.

Comment: I did buy a pvc valve but it has not been installed.

Comment: there should be a sludge cap at the bottom of the oil reservoir in your engine. Remove this and let it leak overnight and then flush it out with water. After this, you should properly dispose of the water since it will still have oil in it. When that is done, it would be fine to put the new oil filter. when you put the new oil filter you will have to bleed this out. If you don't know how to do this visit your local automotive repair shop.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't start the engine, how would anti freeze get into the oil filter?  Altho, if in doubt, change the oil filter, cheap enough.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).